# Pipes.Safe - how to use mapM

Tags: haskell, haskell-pipes, lifting

I have the following code with a pipe which is ok without the second pipe (`>-> P.mapM ( fillMD5)`). `fillMD5` is an operation `a -> IO a`.

```
runSafeT $ runEffect $
     every (senseRecursive5  startfpo)
        >-> P.mapM ( fillMD5)
        >-> P.map fp2rdf  
        >-> toNTriple houtfile
```

The error is :

```
Couldn't match type `IO' with `Pipes.Safe.SafeT IO'
Expected type: Pipes.Safe.SafeT IO ()
  Actual type: IO ()
In the second argument of `($)', namely
  `runEffect
```

I understand that the type of `mapM` is

```
mapM :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> Pipe a b m r
```

but I do not see how to lift this into `Safe.SafeT`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`SafeT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-safe-2.0.0/docs/Pipes-Safe.html#g:1) is a monad transformer, and so `SafeT IO` is a composite monad with `IO` wrapped in `SafeT`. To use `fillMD5`, you need to *lift* the computation it produces to the composite monad using `lift` (from the [`MonadTrans`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.1.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Class.html) class):

```
    >-> P.mapM (lift . fillMD5)
```

As `fillMD5` produces an `IO` action, you can also use `liftIO`, which comes from the [`MonadIO`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.1.0/docs/Control-Monad-IO-Class.html) instance of `SafeT`:

```
    >-> P.mapM (liftIO . fillMD5)
```

Comment: thank you very much. i was thinking of lift or liftIO but forgot the composition (ie. (lift fillMD5) ) and did not see my error!